# Rails: How to reuse AWS credentials from ECS using containers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

We have deployed Rails application on AWS(using docker image within container) and using S3 and SES services to upload files and sending Emails.Both We require  AWS access_key_id, secret_access_key and session_token to communicate with AWS S3 and SES. We use **Aws::ECSCredentials** services to get AWS credentials which lasts 6 hours.

After 5.55 hours, we again fetch credentials using Aws::ECSCredentials.new() api call.
We use CarrierWave to upload files to AWS S3 and using CarrierWave initializer as below to set credentials and this works only first 6 hours until credentials do not expires.

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider: "AWS",
    aws_access_key_id: Settings.amazon.access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key: Settings.amazon.secret_access_key,
    region: Settings.amazon.region,
  }

  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_directory  = Settings.amazon.attachments_bucket
  config.fog_public     = false
end
```

Once first time set credentials expire, we again make a call to **Aws::ECSCredentials.new()** to get new credentials. To use new credentials,
we have to **reinitialize CarrierWave** in ImageUploader(inherited from CarrierWave) as below.

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :fog


  **def initialize(*)
    super
    self.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',              # required
      :aws_access_key_id      => 'YOURAWSKEYID',     # required
      :aws_secret_access_key  => 'YOURAWSSECRET',    # required
    }
    self.fog_directory = "YOURBUCKET"
  end
end
```

Is this approach fine to re-initialize CarrierWave everytime?
I fear this may create Ruby memory issue by creating garbage objects. Can someone please help in this? Is there any better approach to handle it?

Comment: By reinitializing, you mean you're redefining the class by calling the snippet above?
Give me a bit more context, I might have an interesting suggestion for you.

Comment: You might not like this answer. Are you using IAM Roles that gives access to S3 and SES? AWS sdks of any languages will handle refreshing tokens on the fly when it is expired. Your ECS task definition should specify the IAM role and the SDKs when initiated will find the credentials chain in several places. For ECS, it is the instance meta profile. 
`s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
resp = s3.list_buckets` Then job done.

Answer (score 1):

Is your company using AWS Single Sign-On (AWS SSO)? If not, I would recommend doing so. This way you could configure the AWS CLI to use those IAM roles securely to have sessions of a desired time period with refreshing tokens. You can find more details at the [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-sso.html)